# Snowflake GET command -> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (Socket Error Number 10054)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

we have a .NET app using the ODBC driver for Snowflake.
COPY INTO command is working fine but GET command is raising error

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (Socket Error Number 10054)

Comment: What version of ODBC driver are you using and can you provide the example of the GET command you're trying to run?

Comment: Hi, will check the versión but I think it’s the latest one. We noticed that the file is actually downloaded but the socket error is raised after it. Probably when connection is closed. 
Thanks